# How to write a Sparql query for checking duplicates without using GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sparql, ontology

I have a fairly complicated Sparql query that I don't know how to write.  Here's a simplified background of the ontology:

A class "Fruit" has subclasses "Apple" and "Mango". Another class "Nutrition" has subclasses "Vitamin" and "Fiber". "fruit_has_nutrition" is a property that has domain "Fruit" and range "Nutrition".

Then I created the following instances:

Apple_1, Mango_1, Vitamin_1, Vitamin_2, Fiber_1 and Fiber_2, Fiber_3.

The following is what Apple_1 and Mango_1 look like:

```
fruit:Apple_1
   rdf:type fruit:Apple ;
   fruit:fruit_has_nutrition fruit:Fiber_1 ;
   fruit:fruit_has_nutrition fruit:Fiber_2 ;
   fruit:fruit_has_nutrition fruit:Vitamin_1 ;
   rdfs:label "Apple 1" ;.

fruit:Mango_1
   rdf:type fruit:Mango ;
   fruit:fruit_has_nutrition fruit:Fiber_3 ;
   fruit:fruit_has_nutrition fruit:Vitamin_2 ;
   rdfs:label "Mango 1" ;.
```

Assume that an instance of fruit can contain as many kinds of nutrition as possible, but for each kind, it should only contain 1 instance of that nutrition. If that's the case, Apple_1 violates the assumption because it has two instances of Fiber.

Therefore, the query I want to write is "give me all the fruits which have multiple nutritions of the same kind, and give me the type of those nutritions". With the data above, it should give me back Apple_1 and Fiber.

The challenge part is that I can't just GROUP BY rdf:type because it loses distinctions on the kinds of fruit. I tried MINUS (All fruits - fruits without violation):

```
SELECT  
WHERE {
    ?fruit fruit:fruit_has_nutrition ?nutrition .
    ?nutrition rdf:type ?type .
        MINUS {SELECT   DISTINCT ?fruit ?type
                 WHERE {
                    ?fruit fruit:fruit_has_nutrition ?nutrition .
                    ?nutrition rdf:type ?type .
                        }
                }
}
```

But that ends up giving me nothing.

Is there a way to group by two variables? How else can I write this query?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Mmmm; you need an aggregated value of 2 but as I'm not familiar with this syntax all I can offer is an SQL approach ,if it is useless I will remove it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the problem, but why can't you group by fuit type as well?

As usual, no minimal sample data that can be used for testing, thus, an untested query that might be wrong:

```sql
select ?fruit ?fruit_type {
  ?fruit fruit:fruit_has_nutrition ?nutrition .
  ?nutrition rdf:type ?fruit_type .
}
group by ?fruit ?fruit_type
having (count(?nutrition) > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works! Appreciated! I think I got some parenthesis problem before! Very sorry!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to "Accept" this answer if it provides the correct solution.

Comment: Yes the question is solved! Thank you very much everyone!